# Read and write struct with unistd.h read/write

Tags: c, unix

I'm studying UNIX programming and was experimenting with read/write system calls.
I have a file with a pair of integer:

```
4 5
```

and I wrote this code to read the numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef struct prova {
    int first;
    int second;
} prova_t;

int main(void) {
    int fd;
prova_t origin;
prova_t result;
ssize_t bytes_read;
size_t nbytes;

fd = open("file.bin", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
origin.first = 24;
origin.second = 3;
write(fd, &origin, sizeof(prova_t));
close(fd);


fd = open("file.bin", O_RDONLY);
nbytes = sizeof(prova_t);
/* 1.BAD */
bytes_read = read(fd, &result, nbytes);
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &(result.first), sizeof(int));
write(STDOUT_FILENO, &(result.second), sizeof(int));
close(fd);

    /* 2.GOOD */
    nbytes = sizeof(int);
    bytes_read = read(fd, &(result.first), nbytes);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &(result.first), bytes_read);
    bytes_read = read(fd, &(result.second), nbytes);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &(result.second), bytes_read);

    return 0;
}
```

In my first attempt I tried to read the whole struct from file and write its members to stdout. In this way, along with the numbers, I get some weird characters

```
4 5
E�^�
```

In my second attempt I read the numbers one by one and there were no problems in the output.

Is there any way to read and write the struct using the first method?

*Edit: I updated the code to reflect suggestion from other users but still getting strange characters instead of numbers*

Comment: DeadMG is right, but I am wondering if there might not be another aspect: does your input file contain the text "4 5", or is it a binary file holding the numbers 4 and 5 in binary form?

Comment: Reading other suggestions I tried writing the struct on file using write and reading it back, but the problem persist. I updated my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's do a hex dump to see what is really stored in the file.

`hexdump -C b.txt` or `od -t x2 -t c b.txt` are two examples (od is for octal dump, more common, less pretty output in my opinion)

```
00000000  34 20 35 0a                                       |4 5.|
00000004
```

That's is what the file looks like if it was a created as an ASCII text file (such as using a text editor like vi). You can use `man ascii` to double check the hexadecimal values.

Now if you had a binary file that only contains two 8-bit bytes, in the system's native byte ordering (e.g. little-endian for x86, big endian for MIPS, PA-RISC, 680x0) then the hexdump would look like:

```
00000000  04  05                                            |..|
00000004
```

Here is the code to both create (open & write) a binary file, and read it back.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>     /* uint32_t */
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* User has read & write perms, group and others have read permission */ 
const mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;

typedef struct prova {
   uint32_t first;
   uint32_t second;
} prova_t;

#define FILENAME "file.b"

/* 'Safe' write */
int safewrite( int fd, const void *p, size_t want) {
   int ret;

   errno = 0;
   while (want) {
      ret = write(fd, (uint8_t *)p, want);
      if (ret <= 0) {
         if (errno != EINTR && errno != EAGAIN) {
            return -1;
         }
         errno = 0;
         continue;
      }
      want -= ret;
      p = (uint8_t*) p + ret;
   }
   return 0;
}

int saferead(int fd, const void *p, size_t want) {
   int ret;

   errno = 0;
   while (want) {
      ret = read(fd, (uint8_t*)p, want);
      if( ret == 0 )
         return -1;  /* EOF */
      if (ret <= 0) {
         if( errno != EINTR && errno != EAGAIN ) {
            return -1;
         }
         errno = 0;
         continue;
      }
      want -= ret;
      p = (uint8_t*) p + ret;
   }
   return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int fd;
   prova_t result;
   size_t nbytes;

   /* Create file */
   fd = creat(FILENAME, mode);
   if (fd < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open " FILENAME ": %s\n",
            strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   nbytes = sizeof(prova_t);

   result.first = 4;
   result.second = 5;

   if (0 != safewrite(fd, &result, nbytes)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to write to " FILENAME ": %s\n",
            strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   close(fd);
   fd = -1;

   /* Reopen and read from binary file */
   fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDONLY);
   nbytes = sizeof(prova_t);

   if (0 != saferead(fd, &result, nbytes)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read file \"" FILENAME "\": %s\n",
            strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   close(fd);

   printf( "Read: %d %d (%#.02x%.02x)\n",
         result.first, result.second,
         result.first, result.second);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now the data file contents look like:

```
00000000  04 00 00 00 05 00 00 00                           |........|
00000008
```

Because the integers were specified as 32-bit integers (32-bits / 8 bits per byte = 4 bytes). I'm using a 64-bit system (little endian, x86), so I wanted to be explicit so the your results should match, assuming little-endian.

Comment: I should note the very important detail, for when dealing with binary files in *read life*, is that you cannot rely on structures to be written as you want when dumping them to disk. In C, the compiler has the right to silently pad a structure to align structure members so as to be accessible on memory boundaries. Ref: http://c-faq.com/struct/align.html and Michael Crawford's http://www.goingware.com/tips/getting-started/alignment.html

Comment: +1 for actually doing the right thing, i.e. checking the number of bytes actually read or written.

Answer (score 0):

From the name of your file, I assume that you are trying to read a text file. read from unistd.h reads from binary files. If you are indeed trying to read from a text file, you should use [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/) or in [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ifstream/)

To read a struct in binary:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef struct prova {
    int first;
    int second;
} prova_t;

int main(void) {
    int fd;
    prova_t result;
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    size_t nbytes;
    prova_t initial;

    // create a binary file
    fd = open("file.bin", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    initial.first = 4;
    initial.second = 5;
    write(fd, &initial, sizeof(prova_t));
    close(fp);

    // read it back
    fd = open("file.bin", O_RDONLY);
    nbytes = sizeof(prova_t);
    bytes_read = read(fd, &result, nbytes);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &(result.first), sizeof(int));
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &(result.second), sizeof(int));
    close(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know there are other ways: I was asking if it's possible to read and then print on stdout a struct using only write/read system calls.

Comment: Uhm, it makes sense, but it doesn't function. It print only weird characters :(

Comment: That is because the binary numbers are written directly to stdout, instead of translating them into text. For example, to see the character '4' appear using write(), you would have to write its numeric value 36.

Comment: @Lars: I'd upvote your comment, but ASCII for '4' is 0x34 = 52

Comment: @ninjalj You're right - I shouldn't have written from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to read to a struct containing two ints, by passing a pointer to some data and telling read that you had one int's worth of storage. The first should be

```
bytes_read = read(fd, &result, sizeof(prova_t));
```

Comment: Thank you: it was a typo in the cut&paste. It's correct now, but the output is always corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Include flatbuffers/util.h, there are save and load functions sepeartely

`SaveFile(const char *name, const char *buf, size_t len,
                     bool binary);`

`LoadFile(const char *name, bool binary, std::string *buf);`